# jQuery AjaxForm Plugin and ckeditor posts empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ajaxform

I'm trying to use jQuerys ajaxForm ( http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ ) and CKEditor ( http://ckeditor.com ) together but textarea post empty.

HTML Codes:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST" class="ajaxformhere">
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="sometext" id="sometext"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $('.ajaxformhere').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {  
            var textbox = CKEDITOR.instances.sometext.getData();
            $('#sometext').val(textbox); 
        },
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have no idea why but ckeditor doesn't update textarea element. It posts empty when I try to submit it.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use **`beforeSerialize`** instead of `beforeSubmit` event:

```
$('.ajaxformhere').ajaxForm({
    beforeSerialize: function(form, options) { 
  for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
},
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
});
```